# Issue with declaring class variables

Tags: swift3

I'm implementing Google Maps in my project, because MKLocalSearch doesn't have a complete list of restaurants/bars.  I'm following Google's documentation.  I believe I've uncovered an issue and seek advice on how to solve.

The fist step is variable declaration at the class level:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation?
var mapView: GMSMapView!
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
var zoomLevel: Float = 15.0
```

After following the remaining instructions, my program keeps failing on the mapView line:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                      longitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                      zoom: zoomLevel)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)  //Fails here!
```

The error message in the debugger is: Fatal error:  Unexpectedly found Nil while unwrapping optional value.

So the question is why does the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place-tutorial) declare the mapView variable the way it does?  Don't all variables that ARE NOT optional have to initialize with a value?  Should I declare the variable as Optional?  Seems odd to me that Google Documentation would be incorrect.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring an optional with ! you are telling the compiler whenever I access this optional it will have a value. It means you don't have to stick ! at the end everytime you use it. But it does mean if you haven't set the optional to have a value you will get an error when you access it.

An example of using one would a class member of a UIViewController that you setup in viewDidLoad(). You aren't required to setup a separate init() function for the view controller to initialise the variable but you can pretty much guarantee the entry point for your code is viewDidLoad() and any subsequent code run will have a valid version of this class member.

Search for Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals for more details

Comment: Although looking at your code you should check whether the parameters of the function call GMSMapView.map() are not nil.

Answer (score 0):

you should take optional mapView when there is possibility of having mapView or not. You should always take like this

```
 let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```